# YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi_1.2.2 NullPointerException RemoteSurfaceMediaView

Tags: android-youtube-api

I want to integrate YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi_1.2.2 in my app. But when I use this sdk, I found a exception:

```
* AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
* AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.youtube.player, PID: 22244
* AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void abzx.a()' on a null object reference
* AndroidRuntime: at abtv.e(SourceFile:193)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.RemoteSurfaceMediaView.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:22)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.RemoteSurfaceHolder.a(SourceFile:23)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.ApiPlayerService.c(SourceFile:202)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.ApiPlayerService$13.run(SourceFile:3)
* AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
* AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
* AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
* AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
* AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
* AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this problem, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The YouTube Player API has many obscure issues. To avoid such problems I have built an open source player that can be used as an alternative to the official player. You won't have this kind of issues using it: [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).